# how to trigger only documentation box in monaco-editor programatically

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, ngx-monaco-editor

Is there a way to programmatically trigger only the documentation box ( highlighted in the below image ) with some contents?

[image: documentation box]

A CompletionItemProvider with documentation will show a list of suggested items and when we click the show more icon, it will show the documentation of a particular suggestion item. however, I would like to show the documentation directly with some keypress. we can assign some programmatic behaviour to key press. but is there a way to trigger only the documentation box with some contents?

a code snippet will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Instead similar information is shown provided by the hover provider, when you move the mouse over a function call in the code.

Comment: yes I have come across HoverProvider but the problem with it is, it doesn't have a dedicated close button and it just goes off on mouse movement (which is expected behaviour in case of hover) but I would like to keep it until the user closes it.